# Can't display the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sharelatex

I'm currently writing in sharelatex, but the bibliography won't display, and wherever I try to cite I get the message "Citation... undefined"

The code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel,textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introducion}
\section{Motivation}

Climate change is causing a shift in the precipitation patterns and an 
increase in the global mean temperature. In response to this the spatial
distribution of snow cover, and its corresponding depth, water equivalent
and melting factor are changing \cite{IPCC 2014}. This study will evaluate
the relationship between these variables, and the changes in precipitation
and temperature during the last 30 years, and then comment on what we might
expect in the years 2011-2100.

\chapter{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

At the end I get the message: "Empty bibliography"
Could anybody help with this?

References.bib:

```
@article{Deser et al. 2012, 
    author =    "Clara Deser, Adam Phillips, Vincent Bourdette, Haiyan Teng", 
    title =     "{Uncertainty in climate change projections: the role of internal                variability}",
    journal =   "Climate Dynamics",
    volume =    "38",
    pages =     "527--546",
    year =      "2012",
    DOI =       "10.1007/s00382-010-0977-x"}

@article{Giorgi, 
    author =    "Filippo Giorgi, Colin Jones & Ghassem R. Asrar", 
    title =     "{Addressing climate information needs at the regional level: the                CORDEX framework}",
    year = "    2009",


@article{IPCC 2007, 
    author =    "Contribution of Working Groups 1,2 and 3 to the Fourth Assessment               Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change [Core writing             team, Pachauri, R.K. and Reisinger]", 
    title =     "{Climate Change 2007: Synthesis Report}", 
    page =      "30",
    year =      "2007",


@article{IPCC 2008, 
    author =    "Richard Moss, Mustafa Babiker, Sander Brinkman, Eduardo Calvo, Tim              Carter, Jae Edmonds, Ismail Elgizouli, Seita Emori, Lin Erda, Kathy              Hibbard, Roger Jones, Mikiko Kainuma, Jessica Kelleher, Jean Francois             Lamarque, Martin Manning, Ben Matthews, Jerry Meehl, Leo Meyer, John             Mitchell, Nebojsa Nakicenovic, Brian O’Neill, Ramon Pichs, Keywan                Riahi, Steven Rose, Paul Runci, Ron Stouffer, Detlef van Vuuren, John             Weyant, Tom Wilbanks, Jean Pascal van Ypersele, and Monika Zurek", 
    title =     "{Towards New Scenarios for Analysis of Emissions, Climate Change,               Impacts and Response Strategies}",
    page =      "132",
    year =      "2008",


@article {IPCC 2014, 
    author =    "Core Writing Team, R.K. Pachauri and L.A Meyer(eds)", 
    title =     "{Climate Change 2014: Synthesis Report}",
    page =      "2,4,6",
    year =      "2014",


@article{Moss 2010, 
    author =    "Richard H. Moss, Jae A. Edmonds, Kathy A. Hibbard, Martin R.                    Manning, Steven K. Rose, Detlef P. van Vuuren, Timothy R. Carter,                Seita Emori, Mikiko Kainuma, Tom Kram, Gerald A. Meehl, John F. B.               Mitchell, Nebojsa Nakicenovic, Keywan Riahi, Steven J. Smith, Ronald             J. Stouffer, Allison M. Thomson, John P. Weyant & Thomas                         J. Wilbanks", 
    title =     "{The next generation of scenarios for climate change research and               assessment}", 
    journal =   "Nature",
    volume =    "463",
    pages =     "747--756",
    year =      "2010",
    DOI =       "10.1038/nature08823"}

@article{Pithan et al. 2014, 
    author =    "Felix Pithan & Thorsten Mauritsen", 
    title =     "{Arctic amplification dominated by temperature feedbacks in                     contemporary climate models}", 
    journal =   "Nature Geosciences",
    volume =    "7",
    pages =     "181--184",
    year =      "2014",
    DOI =       "10.1038/ngeo2071"}

@article{Rubel et al. 2010,
    author =    "Franz Rubel & Markus Kottek",
    title =     "{Observed and projected climate shifts 1901–2100 depicted by world              maps of the K{\"o}̈ppen-Geiger climate classificatio}n",
    journal =   "Meteorologische Zeitschrift",
    volume =    "19",
    page =  "135--141",
    year =  "2010"}

@article{Taylor et al. 2013, 
    author =    "Patrick C. Taylor, Ming Cai, Aixe Hue, Jerry Meehl, Warren                      Wahington, Guang J. Zhang", 
    title =     "A Decomposition of Feedback Contributions to Polar Warming                      Amplification", 
    journal =   "Climate", 
    volume =    "26",
    pages =     "7023--7043",
    DOI =       "http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/JCLI-D-12-00696.1"}

@article{Vuuren et al 2011, 
    auhor =     "Detlef P.van Vuuren, Jae Edmonds, Mikiko Kainuma, Keywan Riahi,                 Allison Thomson, Kathy Hibbard, George C. Hurtt, Tom Kram, Volker                Krey, Jean-Francois LAmarque, Toshihiko Masui, Malte Meinshausen,                Nebojsa Nakicenovic, Steven J. Smith, Steven K. Rose",
    title =     "The representative concentration pathways: an overview", 
    journal =   "Climatic Change",
    volume =    "109",
    number =    "1-2",
    page =      "5",
    year =      "2011",
    DOI =       "10.1007/s10584-011-0148-z"}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ShareLaTeX should run that automatically I think, unless one has to tell it to use biber instead of bibtex.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Perhaps it does. I don't use such distracting 'tools' ;-)

Comment: No, this isn't compilable yet

Comment: Where is References.bib located? Any other warnings, errors? If you look at  the various log files available, there is one *blg file*, what does that say?

Comment: It's in the same folder. The other messages are: "Entry ... doesn't parse correctly", "Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards"
I can't open the blg file

Comment: Then your bib-file is faulty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do I correct it?

Comment: Your entries (at least one) has a format that is unexpected to the bibliography processor. You need to correct that entry.

Comment: We cannot know what is wrong with an entry unless you show us what it looks like, so could you add the offending entry/entries from the `.bib` file to your question?

Comment: First thing i can spot: a single `&` but it should be `\&`. Since they are between uthors, they should probably be replaced by `and` (see below).

Comment: Also all names should be separated by the word *and* no matter what language you are writing in. `and` is something like a magic word.

Comment: Another problem is that the closing `}` is missing from several of the entries.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's only here. In the references I've included links, and closed them with a }, but I couldn't post more than 2 links here so I just delete them

Comment: @Johannes_B Ok, done that, still I get the message "Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

Comment: Have you checked the blg-file again? Maybe there are some errors left?

Comment: @Johannes_B I can't open it, I dont' have the program necessary

Comment: Huh? You are on Sharelatex, you don't need a extra program. There is a button like *see raw logs* where you can finally find the blg-file.

Comment: It's just a plain text file, so Notepad, Wordpad, Gedit, Kate, or any other text editor can open it.

Comment: @Johannes_B   182] Utils.pm:163> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/ap4vN057Gc/References.bib_14.utf8, line 1, syntax error: found "and", expected ","

Comment: Did you by any chance replace *all* commas by `and`?

Comment: `"Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards." ` is not an error. It is just telling you to run Biber and recompile. Usually this is because you have used citation keys which weren't processed in a previous Biber run. You always get this the first time you compile the document, for example.

Comment: However, I'd guess ShareLaTeX does this automatically so it would usually mean you have used keys which don't exist in the `.bib`. But the error is a different matter, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Problems with the `.bib` file:

- Authors should *always* be separated by the word `and`. Not a comma, not `&`.
- I don't think you can have spaces in the citation keys, so use `IPCC2014`, not `IPCC 2014`.
- The missing braces at the end of most entries you were aware of.
- There's an extra `¨` in the Rubel et al citation.
- Not causing an error I think, but there is an `editor` field that you use for e.g. IPCC2014.
- In `IPCC2007` you need braces around the author field, as it is confused by the two occurrences of `and`, and hence it parses it as three authors. I would recommend finding a better author for that entry though.
- In e.g. `Giorgi`, it would be better to only have braces around `CORDEX`, not the entire title. The same goes for other entries. (See [comment by moeve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300115/cant-display-the-bibliography/300128?noredirect=1#comment734359_300128) below.)

Working `.bib` file:

```
@article{Deseretal2012, 
    author =    "Clara Deser and Adam Phillips and Vincent Bourdette and Haiyan Teng", 
    title =     "Uncertainty in climate change projections: the role of internal variability",
    journal =   "Climate Dynamics",
    volume =    "38",
    pages =     "527--546",
    year =      "2012",
    DOI =       "10.1007/s00382-010-0977-x"}

@article{Giorgi, 
    author =    "Filippo Giorgi and Colin Jones and Ghassem R. Asrar", 
    title =     "Addressing climate information needs at the regional level: the {CORDEX} framework",
    year = "    2009",
}

@article{IPCC2007, 
    author =    "{Contribution of Working Groups 1,2 and 3 to the Fourth Assessment               Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change [Core writing             team, Pachauri, R.K. and Reisinger]}", 
    title =     "Climate Change 2007: Synthesis Report", 
    page =      "30",
    year =      "2007",
}

@article{IPCC2008, 
    author =  "Richard Moss and Mustafa Babiker and Sander Brinkman and Eduardo Calvo and Tim Carter and Jae Edmonds and Ismail Elgizouli and Seita Emori and Lin Erda and Kathy Hibbard and Roger Jones and Mikiko Kainuma and Jessica Kelleher and Jean Francois Lamarque and Martin Manning and Ben Matthews and Jerry Meehl and Leo Meyer and John Mitchell and Nebojsa Nakicenovic and Brian O’Neill and Ramon Pichs and Keywan                Riahi and Steven Rose and Paul Runci and Ron Stouffer and Detlef van Vuuren and John Weyant and Tom Wilbanks and Jean Pascal van Ypersele and Monika Zurek", 
    title =     "Towards New Scenarios for Analysis of Emissions, Climate Change, Impacts and Response Strategies",
    page =      "132",
    year =      "2008"
}

@article{IPCC2014, 
    author =    "{Core Writing Team}",
    editor= "R.K. Pachauri and L.A Meyer", 
    title =     "{Climate Change 2014: Synthesis Report}",
    page =      "2,4,6",
    year =      "2014"
}

@article{Moss2010, 
    author =    "Richard H. Moss and Jae A. Edmonds and Kathy A. Hibbard and Martin R.                    Manning and Steven K. Rose and Detlef P. van Vuuren and Timothy R. Carter and                Seita Emori and Mikiko Kainuma and Tom Kram and Gerald A. Meehl and John F. B.               Mitchell and Nebojsa Nakicenovic and Keywan Riahi and Steven J. Smith and Ronald             J. Stouffer and Allison M. Thomson and John P. Weyant  and Thomas                         J. Wilbanks", 
    title =     "The next generation of scenarios for climate change research and assessment", 
    journal =   "Nature",
    volume =    "463",
    pages =     "747--756",
    year =      "2010",
    DOI =       "10.1038/nature08823"
    }

@article{Pithanetal2014, 
    author =    "Felix Pithan  and Thorsten Mauritsen", 
    title =     "Arctic amplification dominated by temperature feedbacks in contemporary climate models", 
    journal =   "Nature Geosciences",
    volume =    "7",
    pages =     "181--184",
    year =      "2014",
    DOI =       "10.1038/ngeo2071"
    }

@article{Rubeletal2010,
    author =    "Franz Rubel  and Markus Kottek",
    title =     "Observed and projected climate shifts 1901–2100 depicted by world maps of the {K{\"o}ppen-Geiger} climate classification",
    journal =   "Meteorologische Zeitschrift",
    volume =    "19",
    page =  "135--141",
    year =  "2010"}

@article{Tayloretal2013, 
    author =    "Patrick C. Taylor and Ming Cai and Aixe Hue and Jerry Meehl and Warren                      Wahington and Guang J. Zhang", 
    title =     "A Decomposition of Feedback Contributions to Polar Warming Amplification", 
    journal =   "Climate", 
    volume =    "26",
    pages =     "7023--7043",
    DOI =       "http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/JCLI-D-12-00696.1"
    }


@article{Vuurenetal2011, 
    auhor =     "Detlef P. van Vuuren and Jae Edmonds and Mikiko Kainuma and Keywan Riahi and                 Allison Thomson and Kathy Hibbard and George C. Hurtt and Tom Kram and Volker                Krey and Jean-Francois Lamarque and Toshihiko Masui and Malte Meinshausen and                Nebojsa Nakicenovic and Steven J. Smith and Steven K. Rose",
    title =     "The representative concentration pathways: an overview", 
    journal =   "Climatic Change",
    volume =    "109",
    number =    "1-2",
    page =      "5",
    year =      "2011",
    DOI =       "10.1007/s10584-011-0148-z"
    }
```

Comment: The issue with needing `{}` around the author is, I think, not to do with the commas but because otherwise BibTeX/Biber tries to interpret it as a *string*. If the string is defined, it works fine. Here it isn't, so it doesn't. (Essentially all authors in my `.bib` files are defined in `authors.bib` using strings so I hardly ever have `{}` around author! Worth +1 anyway, though!

Comment: @cfr Thanks, somehow I didn't see your comment earlier. I also realized that `and` occurs twice as a word (not a separator) in that author, which messes things up of course. I don't even know how strings are defined in this context ...

Comment: One should also add extra braces around the author fields in `IPCC2007`, `IPCC2014`. In `Vuurenetal2011` a space is missing before the van in "Detlef P.van Vuuren". I would not protect entire fields with a `"{...}"` combination, only protect those words that need to be capitalised at all times and choose a proper style.

Comment: The strings cfr talked about are `@string` entries one can use to avoid having to write out often used fields. You have a `@string{anch-ie = {Angew.~Chem. Int.~Ed.}}` entry and use it as `@article{bronto,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {Brontos},
  journaltitle = anch-ie,
  date         = 2006,
  }` without `"` or `{...}`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot! `IPCC2007` has braces, will add for 2014 as well, and fix `Giorgi`.